# Mock the creation of a subscription with Azure SDK in .net

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

for testing I need to mock the creation of Azure Subscriptions. I am using the Azure SDK with version "1.6.0".

The code which needs to be tested looks like:

```
   ...
   tenantResource = ... // I am able to get a mocked version of the tenantResource

   tenantResource 
   **.GetSubscriptionAliases()**
   .CreateOrUpdateAsync(
        WaitUntil.Completed,
        ...
   )
```

The call to `GetSubscriptionAliases()` method gives me troubles because the function is a extension method forwarding to `GetExtensionClient` (as well static) and this one to `GetCachedClient` method.

```
    public static SubscriptionAliasCollection GetSubscriptionAliases(this TenantResource tenantResource)
    {
        return GetExtensionClient(tenantResource).GetSubscriptionAliases();
    }
```

The `GetCachedClient` could be mocked but the return type `TenantResourceExtensionClient` is an internal class, which I can not access in my project.

So how could I mock the SubscriptionAliasCollection ?. Is there maybe a better approach to create a subscription in a tenant, which would be easier to test?

I am looking for your answers.

Best regards.